# Why do SQL Server Profiles only work on 32 bit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Why do SQL Server Profiles only work on 32 bit?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: SSIS Log Providers

Comment: This now makes even less sense. Can you try to provide some details to your question?

Comment: I am working on a SQL Data Warehouse document. Logging says that SSIS Package Events is only 32 bits for sql server profiler when it describes log providers. I wonder why.